# How to reference a default certificate by Azure App service to configure IdentityServer4?

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-web-app-service

I have created an app for authentication/authorization with IdentityServer4 and Asp.Net Core and everything is working perfect when i use localhost. Now I would like to put it in production.

I have published the app using Azure App Service successfully.
The app uses SSL and has a certificate that was automatically created on publishing.

As far as I have learned, I must now replace

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer().AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
```

with

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential()
```

And then add a certificate to `AddSigningCredential()`.

When I go to *Azure portal -> the app -> settings -> TSL/SSL settings* I cannot find the default certificate. When I try to buy a new certificate it says:

> "Domain already protected by SSL. All App Service Web Apps have SSL
>   enabled by default for the default site URL"

How can I reach the certificate in my startup code so that I can add it to `AddSingingCredential()`?

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is "use a certificate (configured for your app SSL) to also sign the IdentityServer4 tokens".

Please take a look at the documentation from microsoft on how to achieve this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code